# checking  app download completion from my own app

Tags: cocoa, download, nsurl, outlook-redemption

so what I'm trying to do here is the following: let's say the user has already installed my app, app "A", from the store. On certain conditions, app "A" will open an URL pointing to a specific app page,app "B", on the App Store passing a redemption code so the user of app A is able to download app "B" without paying any additional money. So here's what I'm doing:

`NSString *urlBase = @"https://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=";`

`NSURL *urlRedemptionCode = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlBase stringByAppendingString:code]];`

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlRedemptionCode];`

This is working fine, so the question is: how do I know that the download of app "B" was completed correctly (or with errors) so I can take appropriate action in app "A"?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSURLConnection` in combination with `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLResponse` instead of directly calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:yourURL]`.

`NSURLConnection` will allow you to set a delegate that will be notified when:

- Data is (partially) received
- Connection failed
- Download finished
- etc.

Check [Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) at the official documentation.